# Kprototype algorithm tuple index out of range

Tags: python, algorithm

I am creating a clustering algorithm with Kprototype algorithm in a Django app.

Nowadays I am testing all my algorithm with false data to understand how it works and to validate how it works.

My cluster and predict functions are:

```
def ClusterCreation(request,*args):
    global kproto
    # random categorical data
    data = np.array([
            [0,'a',4],
            [1,'e',3],
            [3,'ffe',7],
            [5,'fdfd',16]
            ])

    kproto = KPrototypes(n_clusters=2, init='Cao', verbose=2)
    clusters = kproto.fit_predict(data, categorical=[1,2])

    # Create CSV with cluster statistics
    clusterStatisticsCSV(kproto)
    for argument in args:
        if argument is not None:
            return

    # Print the cluster centroids
    return HttpResponse('Clustering ok')

def ClusterPrediction(request):

    global kproto

    if (kproto==0):
        ClusterCreation(None,1)

    # random point to fit
    data = np.array([0,'a',4])
    fit_label = kproto.predict(data, categorical=[0,1]) #categorical is the Index of columns that contain categorical data

    # Print the cluster centroids
    return HttpResponse('Point '+str(data)+' is in cluster '+str(fit_label))
```

I achieved to run ClusterCreation function with no problem, but now I am adding the functionality to predict the cluster of a new data point.

You will see a function called `clusterStatisticsCSV` it works without problem and is a simple CSV export.

I am getting the following error log:

```
Initialization method and algorithm are deterministic. Setting n_init to 1.
dz01     | Init: initializing centroids
dz01     | Init: initializing clusters
dz01     | Starting iterations...
dz01     | Run: 1, iteration: 1/100, moves: 0, ncost: 8.50723954060097
dz01     | Internal Server Error: /cluster/clusterPrediction/
dz01     | Traceback (most recent call last):
dz01     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
dz01     |     response = get_response(request)
dz01     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
dz01     |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
dz01     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
dz01     |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
dz01     |   File "/src/cluster/views.py", line 62, in ClusterPrediction
dz01     |     fit_label = kproto.predict(data, categorical=[0,1]) #categorical is the Index of columns that contain categorical data
dz01     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kmodes/kprototypes.py", line 438, in predict
dz01     |     Xnum, Xcat = _split_num_cat(X, categorical)
dz01     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kmodes/kprototypes.py", line 44, in _split_num_cat
dz01     |     Xnum = np.asanyarray(X[:, [ii for ii in range(X.shape[1])
dz01     | IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I understand which is the error, and I guess that is related with:
`kproto.predict(data, categorical=[0,1])`. Specifically, with the categorical column index. Despite applying changes to test another values and get a solution I have not been able to fully understand what happens and solve it.

My worries also are related with the same categorical parameter at `ClusterCreation` function, because probably also is wrong and then clusters are wrong.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The data array had a mistake: 
**Previous:**
`data = np.array([0, 'a', 3])`
**Correct:**
`data = np.array([[0, 'a', 3]])`

Despite that I read all the `Kprototype.py` file and I have seen that `Categorical` is a parameter that indicates the index of each variable with categorical data in a multiarray. So, If you say, `categorical=[1,2]` you are saying that the second and the third column (python index starts with 0) are categorical variables.

An example multiarray for this is:

```
data = np.array([
            [0,'a','rete'],
            [1,'e','asd'],
            ])
```